# ¿Cómo restar los elementos de columnas con python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

tengo una duda con respecto a Python.

Tengo el siguiente programa:

```
import pandas as pd 

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 

numbers_1 = [15,20,14,18,14,13,12,15,17,16]

numbers_2 = [3,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,1,2]

df = pd.DataFrame({'numeros': numbers_1, 'valores': numbers_2})

print(df)

elemento_1 = df.iloc[0:,0]

elemento_2 = df.iloc[1:,1]

print(elemento_1)

print(elemento_2)
```

Estoy generando un DataFrame con dos columnas lo que quisiera saber, es como puedo restar el primer valor de la primera columna con el segundo valor de la segunda columna, y así consecutivamente hasta dar con el ultimo valor y que me muestre resultados en una columna aparte.

¿Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes  usar [`pandas.Series.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.shift.html?highlight=shift#pandas.Series.shift) para "desplazar" la segunda columna, el resto es simplemente una operación de resta vectorizada entre Series:

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'numeros': (15, 20, 14, 18, 14, 13, 12, 15, 17, 16),
                   'valores': (3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2)
                   })

df["resultado"] = df["numeros"] - df["valores"].shift(-1)
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>    numeros  valores  resultado
> 0       15        3       13.0
> 1       20        2       17.0
> 2       14        3       13.0
> 3       18        1       14.0
> 4       14        4       11.0
> 5       13        3       11.0
> 6       12        2        9.0
> 7       15        3       14.0
> 8       17        1       15.0
> 9       16        2        NaN
> ```

El argumento `-1` se corresponde con el periodo (argumento periods), es decir, equivale a:

```
df["valores"].shift(periods=-1)
```

Desplaza la columna (`Serie`) el número deseado de períodos. Si el escalar es positivo la serie se desplaza hacia "abajo" rellenando las filas iniciales con `NaN`:

> ```
> >>> s = pd.Series((2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13))
> >>> s
> 0     2
> 1     3
> 2     5
> 3     7
> 4    11
> 5    13
> dtype: int64
>
> >>> s.shift(1)  
> 0     NaN
> 1     2.0
> 2     3.0
> 3     5.0
> 4     7.0
> 5    11.0
> dtype: float64
>
> >>> s.shift(2)
> 0    NaN
> 1    NaN
> 2    2.0
> 3    3.0
> 4    5.0
> 5    7.0
> dtype: float64
> ```

Si es negativo se desplaza hacia "arriba":

> ```
> >>> s.shift(-1) 
> 0     3.0
> 1     5.0
> 2     7.0
> 3    11.0
> 4    13.0
> 5     NaN
> dtype: float64
> ```

Por lo tanto, si quieres que el `NaN` quede en la primera fila, basta con aplicar el desplazamiento a la primera columna en vez de a la segunda, pero en este caso positivo:

> ```
> >>> df["resultado"] = df["numeros"].shift(1) - df["valores"]
>
> >>> df
>    numeros  valores  resultado
> 0       15        3        NaN
> 1       20        2       13.0
> 2       14        3       17.0
> 3       18        1       13.0
> 4       14        4       14.0
> 5       13        3       11.0
> 6       12        2       11.0
> 7       15        3        9.0
> 8       17        1       14.0
> 9       16        2       15.0
> ```

Si deseas que la columna sea de tipo entero si o si debes hacer un casting a `Int8`, `Int16`, `Int32` o `Int64` de forma explícita (observa que la "I" inicial es mayúscula). El 8, 16, etc hace referencia a los bits que se usan y por tanto el máximo valor capaz de almacenar, debes ajustarlo en función del rango de enteros esperado para ajustar el uso de memoria.

> Esto solo es posible a partir de [Pandas 0.24.x](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.24/whatsnew/v0.24.0.html#optional-integer-na-support), antes `NaN` solo era posible representarlo con tipo floats.

```
import pandas as pd 

df = pd.DataFrame({'numeros': (15, 20, 14, 18, 14, 13, 12, 15, 17, 16),
                   'valores': (3, 2, 3, 1, 4, 3, 2, 3, 1, 2)
                   })

df["resultado"] = (df["numeros"].shift(1) - df["valores"]).astype("Int64")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    numeros  valores  resultado
> 0       15        3        NaN
> 1       20        2         13
> 2       14        3         17
> 3       18        1         13
> 4       14        4         14
> 5       13        3         11
> 6       12        2         11
> 7       15        3          9
> 8       17        1         14
> 9       16        2         15
> ```

Comment: ¿Por que el shif(-1)?

Comment: ¿Como puedo hacer que ese NaN me quede arriba?

Comment: En la fila cero , tercera columna

Comment: Los números son flotantes

Comment: Seria recomendable que salga enteros, es que voy a trabajar con muchos datos

Comment: Pudiste editar la respuesta?

Comment: Estoy en ello, estoy con un smartphone y es un supliciooo... XD

Comment: Ohhhhh, ya veo, si debe ser muy lento xD

Comment: Por fin, hecho.... :) a ver si resuelve todas tus dudas.