# Insertar una columna en un DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Hola soy nuevo en python, podian ayudarme, tengo las listas numbers_1 y numbers_2, esto lo he pasado a un DataFrame, y he logrado restar ambas columnas, al ultimo con el for logro obtener una nueva lista, la cual es el resultado.
Mi duda es como puedo poner esa lista como una nueva columna en ese DataFrame, mi código es el siguiente.

```
import pandas as pd 





numbers_1 = [15,20,14,18,14,13,12,15,17,16]

numbers_2 = [3,2,3,1,4,3,2,3,1,2]

resultado = []

df = pd.DataFrame({'numeros': numbers_1, 'valores': numbers_2})

elemento_1 = df.iloc[0:9,0]

elemento_2 = df.iloc[1:,1]



elemento_lista_1 = list(elemento_1)

elemento_lista_2 = list(elemento_2)

print(elemento_lista_1)

print(elemento_lista_2)



for i in range(len(elemento_lista_1)):

    resultado.append(elemento_lista_1[i]-elemento_lista_2[i])


print(resultado)

df.insert(2, "Age", resultado, True)

print(df)
```

Comment: Solo quieres una nueva columna con la resta de `numbers_1` y `numbers_2`?

Comment: Puedes probar algo asi: `df['Age'] = df['numeros'] - df['valores'].shift(-1)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primero de todo, existe una forma más simple y eficiente de resolver este problema de forma vectorizada con Pandas sin recurrir a un ciclo `for` de Python estándar:

- [¿Cómo restar los elementos de columnas con python?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330760/c%c3%b3mo-restar-los-elementos-de-columnas-con-python/330795#330795)

Dicho esto, el problema es que la lista `resultado` tiene como cabe esperar un elemento menos que las filas de `df`, lo cual nos genera un error esperado:

> ValueError: Length of values does not match length of index

Un truco es usar una serie, lo cual hace que de forma automática se rellenen las filas faltantes con `NaN` (al final):

```
df["Age"] = pd.Series(resultado, dtype="Int64")
```

> ```
> >>> df
>    numeros  valores  Age
> 0       15        3   13
> 1       20        2   17
> 2       14        3   13
> 3       18        1   14
> 4       14        4   11
> 5       13        3   11
> 6       12        2    9
> 7       15        3   14
> 8       17        1   15
> 9       16        2  NaN
> ```

Si quieres que los valores NaN se agreguen al inicio ya no es tan simple, puedes agregarlo manualmente:

```
import numpy as np

resultado.insert(0, np.nan)
df["Age"] = resultado
```

o puedes crear una función que lo haga de forma automática comparando ambas longitudes.