# como agregar un columna a un dataframe con pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

tengo este codigo:

```
prueba=pd.dataframe({'precio':[precio], 'umbral':[umbral]})
```

quiero agregar una columna adicional con otra linea de codigo a prueba.

Comment: ¿algo así `prueba['NuevaColumna'] = valor`?

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Insertar una columna en un DataFrame](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/330792/insertar-una-columna-en-un-dataframe)